# Where does the LINE app store pictures and video files?

Tags: files, line

Where does the [LINE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.naver.line.android) app store pictures and videos that are received through it?

I don't see them in Gallery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Pictures and videos from the LINE app are stored under the following directory:

   ```
    /sdcard/Android/data/jp.naver.line.android/storage/gallerybig
   ```
2. All the audio files are placed under directory:

   ```
    /sdcard/Android/data/jp.naver.line.android/cache/mo/(folder)/[audio files]
   ```
3. Profile pictures are cached in directory:

   ```
    /sdcard/Android/data/jp.naver.line.android/storage/p
   ```

Just rename the files to `.jpg` to view them.

**Update:**

With recent update, the download folder name for image, video, and voice files has been changed to `LINE`. Please check the `LINE` folder when you look for files.

**Update on 18 Feb. 2021**

Today I check for a video (*.mp4) file, and find it deep somewhere under .../storage/mo with strange folder names, so you'd better use a file manager to search it.