# Where does LINE store profile pictures?

Tags: line

Similar to: [Where does the LINE app store pictures and video files?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/where-does-line-app-stores-the-pictures-and-video-files) , but in that folder I can't see any profile picture

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does Line app stores the pictures and video files?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/where-does-line-app-stores-the-pictures-and-video-files)

Answer (score 2):

Profile pictures are cached in the following directory:

```
/sdcard/Android/data/jp.naver.line.android/storage/p
```

Rename the extension of files to *.jpg* to view them.